# getDirection() in JS to determine the direction in BPF in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have written the following code onSave of Opportunity Entity:

```
function bpf(executionContext)
{
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    formContext.data.process.addOnStageChange(function () {
      //  debugger;
        //alert("JS called");
        var stageName = formContext.data.process.getSelectedStage().getName().toString().toLowerCase();
        //alert(stageName);
        var accountApproved = formContext.getAttribute("new_accountstatusapproved");
        var direction = executionContext.getEventArgs().getDirection();

        //alert(direction);

        if (stageName != "" && stageName === "check status" && accountApproved != null && accountApproved.getValue() != null && accountApproved.getValue() == 0)
        {
            //debugger;
            formContext.data.process.movePrevious();
            formContext.ui.setFormNotification("The Account is not Approved.", "WARNING", "1");
        }

    });
}
```

Basically, I need to get the direction of the BPF using the following line :

```
var direction = executionContext.getEventArgs().getDirection();
```

getDirection() is not working as expected. The control is going to some other function in ribbon.js and is taking infinite amount of time.

What have I missed here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

executionContext is a reference to the save event. You modify your addOnStageChange callback function to receive the stage context

```
function bpf(executionContext)
{
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    formContext.data.process.addOnStageChange(function (stageContext) {

        var direction = stageContext.getEventArgs().getDirection();

        ...
    });
}
```